# Make error: missing separator on first line of Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am getting the following error when try to run make:

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Looks like I need to use tab on my first line.
However, first 3 lines of my Makefile is like this.

```
[ -z "${PROJ_DIR}" ] && PROJ_DIR=/home/my_directory
[ -z "${BASE_DIR}" ] && BASE_DIR=/home/my_directory
[ -z "${TOOLCHAIN}" ] && TOOLCHAIN=${BASE_DIR}/mips-4.3
```

There is no where for any space modification.
I am lost to what the error could be.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your Makefile?

Comment: That's a shell script, not a makefile.

Comment: I want to give user an option to set environment variables else use the default that is given.can you not use script in a makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not even *close* to [correct makefile syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors).

```
PROJ_DIR ?= /home/my_directory
BASE_DIR ?= /home/my_directory
TOOLCHAIN ?= $(BASE_DIR)/mips-4.3
```

Comment: thanks that seems to explain it, but I had Makefile with the above written code worked before(my code). Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because you were using it in a production stanza.